# picture appears as white space in button

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, icons, uitoolbar

I downloaded from a free icon DB a thumb up icon, its size is too large for a button and it had white background.I decided to open it in pixelmator resized the icon and removed the background. when opening it with preview it looks great but when its set to be the button's image in xcode it appears as a white circle.

here is the icon after edit (30x30 png) 
[image] 
and this is how it looks on the button [image]

what should I do to fix this?

**edit/ upadte:**
I tried @yunas code and it works in the navigation bar **not for the toolbar** (didn't even show the button).

Trying this code:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];
UIBarButtonItem *likeBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(action_clicked:)];
NSArray* toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:likeBtn,nil];
self.toolbarItems = toolbarItems;
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
```

resulted again in a button with the white drawing

So I was wondering: Is it even possible to have colored buttons in the toolbar? maybe i'm trying the imposible...

**edit/ upadte II - the solution:**  wrapping a UIButton inside a UIBarButtonItem

```
@interface StatusUIBarButtonItem : UIBarButtonItem
- (id) initWithStatus: (enum StatusEnum)p_statusEnum;
@end

@implementation StatusUIBarButtonItem
- (instancetype)initWithStatus:(enum StatusEnum)p_statusEnum
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[self getStatusImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(status_Clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];

    self = [super initWithCustomView:button];
    if (self) 
    {
        self.statusButton = button;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

then in the ViewController class:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{  
    StatusUIBarButtonItem* stausBtn = [[StatusUIBarButtonItem alloc]  initWithStatus:self.status];
    NSArray* toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: stausBtn, nil];
    self.toolbarItems = toolbarItems;
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
}
```

I hope this will help others that like me want colored images in the toolbar

Comment: you need to set the uibarbuttonitem with a customview

Comment: it's a UIBarButtonItem identifier: custom style:borderd tint: default

Comment: It is expected behavior: "Toolbar images that represent normal and highlighted states of an item derive from the image you set using the inherited image property from the UIBarItem class. For example, the image is converted to white and then bevelled by adding a shadow for the normal state." http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

```
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.adjustsImageWhenDisabled = NO;
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

   UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
```

Comment: You should also set the `UIButton`'s `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` property to `YES`.

Comment: @yunas replaced the imageName of course, and instead of the `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;` i used  `self.navigationController.toolbarItems = @[customBarItem];` but the button still comes out like in the picture a write circle :(

Comment: i have updated the code with leftbarbuttonitem to rightbarbuttonitem and you dont have to do self.navigationcontroller.toolbaritems = @[custombaritem]. please omit this line from your code

Comment: @yunas thanks for your help, your code works in the navigation bar, but I need the buttons in the toolbar ( the bar at the bottom of the screen) again trying this line self.navigationController.toolbarItems = @[customBarItem]; did not work